# Better way to joining tables to pick data from one or other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
BookID  Title           ReleaseYear
1       The Hobbit      1937
2       Atlas Shrugged  1957

BookID  Cost    BookPrinterID
1       12      38

BookID  Charge  BookPublisherID
1       39      148
2       45      151
```

That's the book publishing tables data I have.
Books table, Cost table and Charge table.
I would like to see cost information if present else charge data from single query. i.e.

```
BookID  Cost
1       12
2       45
```

This is my query

```
select Books.BookID, ISNULL(Cost.Cost, Charge.Charge) AS Cost 
from Books
left join Cost on Books.BookID = Cost.BookID
left join Charge on Book.BookID = Charge.BookID
```

That works, but problem is if there are more tables to join or more columns to retrieve, having ISNULL condition for every column will become a big blob of text, especially if you have to parse xml.

```
ISNULL(Cost.Xchange.value('/Partner[1]/@Sales[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'), Charge.Xchange.value('/Partner[1]/@Sales[1]', 'nvarchar(500)')) AS Xchange
```

My question is, is there a neater way to write this query?

Comment: I'll give shortest answer possible - NO! How do you expect to query something without actually doing it? You only use function where necessary. Some columns will never be null. You can restrict your data output with `where Cost.Cost is not null` and your data will never be null. But, yea, you got to write stuff

Answer (score 0):

Using an `INNER join` on both tables, will omit the row for `bookid=2` as there is no record in the `cost` table for it.  You likely want to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` for both tables to show all rows.

That said, what you want is some sort of intermediate table that is a combination of `cost`/`charge` but only when there is no record in `cost`.

You could do something like this, where you populate a new table with all the `cost` records, and then all the `charge` records (where no `cost` is found in the new table)... Although, there would undoubtedly be a performance hit by creating/writing to a new table on the fly.  I wouldn't want to do this in a large library.

Here's a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08984/1) too.

```
create table #books (bookid int, title varchar(50), releaseyear int)
create table #charge (bookid int, charge money, publisherid int)
create table #cost  (bookid int, cost money, bookprinterid int)

insert into #books 
select 1, 'The Hobbit', 1937 union
select 2, 'Atlas Shrugged', 1957

insert into #cost
select 1, 12, 38

insert into #charge
select 1, 39, 148 union
select 2, 45, 151

create table #allcosts (bookid int, cost money)

insert into #allcosts
select c1.bookid, c1.cost from #cost c1

insert into #allcosts
select c2.bookid, c2.charge 
from #charge c2
left outer join #allcosts c3 on c2.bookid=c3.bookid
where c3.bookid is null

select b.BookID, c.cost AS Cost 
from #Books b
inner join #allcosts c on b.bookid = c.bookid
```

Comment: Should I use a temp table? That is even worse than what I had.

Comment: No, you don't have to use temp tables, that was just for demonstration purposes.  But temp tables can easily be indexed on the fly if that is the route you choose.  I totally agree, the performance of this is likely worse than your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

If all rows in Books are not in Cost you can't use inner joins on the 3 tables. Otherwise in your example BookID=2 will never be returned. There is no way around using isNull if you are going to join more tables and retrieve more columns.

```
select bookid, isNull(cost, charge)
from Books b
inner join Charge c
on bt.bookid = c.bookid
left join Cost co
on co.bookid = bt.bookid
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had left join there. My question is, is there a better way to write the above query instead of doing isnull on so many columns. Was basically looking for a shorter version, hoping that it would be neater.